# Heater and AC don't work?

Tags: ac, mitsubishi, heater-blower

Hi I have just got a Mitsubishi Legnum, '96 v6 SR25. My heater and AC does not work all fuses are good.

Comment: Doesn't work how? Does the blower motor blow air out the vents? A little more details would help

Comment: Sorry, no nothing works, can't clear windows without wiping, all options come up on screen but no air comes through any of the vents.

Comment: So, according to the screen, everything *looks* to be functioning, but the van is not coming on? Does this have an automatic climate control system? Is there a manual setting for the fan? Can you hear the A/C compressor kick in when you turn the system on?

Comment: Uhh yes that's exactly right, I am unsure if the CCS is automatic however, it does have an automatic setting. No there is no indication that the compressor has kicked in. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

So I found the issue with the heater was a fried plug. I got a new plug re wired it clipped it in and all systems go. But then as I went up the road I could smell burning plastic so I stopped and unplugged the new plug, and found that one of the male pins was ready to break so now I need to replace this..

Answer (score 0):

Well, with the little information you given, sounds like the blower motor portion of the heater/a.c. is not working. Could just be the blower motor it self(most likely, imo). Could be the climate control head.  If you could locate the blower motor and check to see if it has power when turned on. Or you could get lucky and tap on the motor and it'll start to work. Hope this helps.